# Replace domain name with relative path in a list

Tags: batch-file, replace

I need to replace the domain in a list with more url.

I have a big list of different urls like

```
52.214:5469/en/page2/
50.17.168.29:58477/en/house/
home:58477/en/coder
5550:58477/en/enjoy
```

This list after replaced will be

```
mydomain.com/en/page2/
mydomain.com/en/house/
mydomain.com/en/coder
mydomain.com/en/enjoy
```

All url contain /en/ I need to replace the part before /en/

How can i replace all domain in my list of urls ?

All solution provided do not works because do not recognize the path of the list ("D:\Programmi Installati\Macro\domainlist.txt").

Thanks for suggestion

best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

(for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("D:\Programmi Installati\Macro\domainlist.txt") do (
   set "line=%%a"
   echo !line:*/en/=mydomain.com/en/!
)) > temp.txt
move /Y temp.txt "D:\Programmi Installati\Macro\domainlist.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

C:\Users\pwatson\src\bat>type domainlist.txt

```
52.214:5469/en/page2/
50.17.168.29:58477/en/house/
home:58477/en/coder
5550:58477/en/enjoy
```

C:\Users\pwatson\src\bat>type domainlist.ps1

```
get-content domainlist.txt | % { $_ -replace '(.*?)(/en.*)','mydomain.com$2' }
```

C:\Users\pwatson\src\bat>powershell -file domainlist.ps1

```
mydomain.com/en/page2/
mydomain.com/en/house/
mydomain.com/en/coder
mydomain.com/en/enjoy
```

Comment: I i do not know your solution, where i can insert the path name of the files? Any solution more simple?

Comment: I tried your solution but do not replace nothing there is a problems, my path with the list is "D:\Programmi Installati\Macro\domainlist.txt" I added it in the script but for me this solution do not work, do not replace nothing in my list.

Comment: @placidomaio - I do not know what to say. I copied your data into the file domainlist.txt. I wrote the script in domainlist.ps1. I ran the command line and showed the output. I am not sure what I can do for you. Would you post your code?

Comment: But sorry is normal that the list is saved in the computer and therefore must have a path otherwise the bat how do you know where the list if you do not specify a path ?

Comment: I  placed the file into the current directory. That is why it did not need a path. You should type the directory path if your data file is not in the current directory.

Comment: Thanks to you i prefer the Aacini solution because solve the path problem and works like a charms in every path. thank to all for support